# C++ get unicode character by it's utf-8 value

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

i am not good with c++
and i am trying to create function to convert URL encoded string into regular string.

But i am getting weird results, for example, %C4%93 (decimal 50323) should be utf-8 symbol *ē*, but i am getting *ō* when i print in console.
I tried:

- string+= static_cast(character_integer_value);
- string+= (char)character_integer_value;
- string+= character_integer_value;

but nothing of this gave me output i expected.

Can you please point me what i am doing wrong?

```
std::string myUrldecode(const std::string& original) {
    std::string s = original;
    std::string tmp0 = "";
    int tmp1 = 0;
    int tmp2 = 0;
    std::string decoded = "";

    for (string::size_type i = s.find("%");
        i != string::npos;
        i = s.find("%"))
    {
        if(i > 0){
            decoded+= tmp0;
            tmp0 = "";
            tmp2 = 0;
        }
        decoded+= s.substr(0, i);
        s.erase(0, i);

        tmp0+= s.substr(0, 2);
        tmp1 = strtol(s.substr(1, 2).c_str(), nullptr, 16);

        if(tmp1 >= 20 && tmp1 < 127){
            decoded+= static_cast<char>(tmp1);
            s.erase(0, 3);
            tmp0 = "";
        }
        else if(tmp1 >= 192 && tmp1 < 223){
            tmp2 = tmp1;
            s.erase(0, 3);
        }
        else if(tmp1 >= 128 && tmp1 <= 191 && tmp2 > 192){
            tmp1+= tmp2 * 256;
            decoded+= tmp1;
            s.erase(0, 3);
            tmp0 = "";
        }
        else{
            s.erase(0, 3);
        }
    }
    decoded+= tmp0;
    decoded+= s;
    return decoded;
}
```

I am using Dev-C++ 5.11 with GCC 4.9.2 32 bit to compile that code.

Comment: As a sidenote: If you're going to copy the argument anyway, why not pass by value for simplicity and to allow caller to move the string if they so desire?

Comment: Also, I debugged your program for you. It returns only one character with the given input, instead of 2, so there's something wrong with the logic.

Comment: Ok, i understand, & mean passing value by reference (or pointer, i don't really understood difference yet). But, please, just ignore all my unrelated mistakes, i am sure i have many of them, like not clearing memory etc. In my program i will use this function only once anyway.

Comment: Yes, with input "%C4%93" i expect one character output, "ē".

Comment: But that particular glyph can only be represented by two code points in utf-8. Therefore you need 2 `char`s in your output string.

Comment: Yes, now i am starting to understand that "ē" must be represented by 2 chars. But if i write two chars, then in console output i also get two symbols "─ō" .

Comment: Are you quite sure that your console uses utf-8?

Comment: No, i am not sure. I call program from WinXP Command Prompt, and i can type and see symbol "ē" there. I also tested with same results on Win7. But i cannot see there some other letters i type, so i guess, it is not utf-8...

Comment: Now i store 2 bit symbols in 2 chars each, and it seems to work in "system()" call for some languages(like ē,ā,š) and for some it is not working (like я,ё.ж). I am still unable to print unicode symbols in console or elsewhere, so it is hard to debug.

Comment: Basically user2079303 gave answer to question i asked - std::string consist of chars, which are 1 byte each, and to store utf-8 symbols, more than 1 char must be used.  Outputting this value to console or to system() is different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got it totally wrong.

"%C4%93" **is** the UTF-8 encoding for ē, so you just need to convert the numbers (C4+93) into `char`s.  Instead you seem to be worrying about characters ranges 127-192 etc.

I think the code you have written maybe trying to convert a Unicode code point into UTF-8 (275 -> C493).

Comment: Yes, converting C4 and 93 to two sequential chars may be the right solution.
I don't really get where 275 comes from?

Comment: ē is unicode character U+0113, and 275 is the decimal value of 113 hex.  So ē is code point 275